# URLS loop to get the financials

Tags: python

I have a code where I try to get financials but my problem is I only receiving in excel the first url "income annually" instead of four tabs. Below the code if anybody has any idea what I'm doing wrong and what should change to get four tabs for each link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'}

ticker = "BABA"

urls= {}
urls['income annually']= f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker}/financials/"
urls['balance sheet annually']= f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker}/financials/balance-sheet/"
urls['cash flow annually']= f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker}/financials/cash-flow-statement/"
urls['ratios annually']= f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker}/financials/ratios/"


xlwriter =pd.ExcelWriter(f'financial statements ({ticker}).xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for key in urls.keys():
    response = requests.get(urls[key], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs={'id': 'financial-table'})[0]
    df.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name=key, index=False)

    xlwriter.save()
```

Comment: Can you show your output as well?

Answer (score 4):

The indentation of the last line is erroneous.
It closes the file.

Correction:

```
for key in urls.keys():
    ...
    df.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name=key, index=False)

xlwriter.save()
```